# Regex pattern to find pec+

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-greedy, word-boundaries

I am trying to match the "word" `pec+` in the phrase

> I cannot find pec+

I have tried the pattern `\bpec\+\b`, but there are no matches.

Comment: Do you want to match `pec+` in `&pec+`, `pec+_` or `pec+&`? What about `abc,pec+,def` too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `+` is not a word character, you need to end the expression by matching a *non* word boundary, using `\B`:

```
\bpec\+\B
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/Pk9XRwAhtr), showing match for

```
foo pec+ bar
```

but not for any of:

```
foopec+ bar
foo pec+bar
foopec+bar
```

Answer (score -1):

> A word boundary ( \b ) is defined as a spot between two characters that has
> a \w on one side of it and and a \W on the other side of it (in either order),
> counting the imaginary characters off the beginning and end of the string as
> matching a \W .
>
> @ and + being non word chars, there is no \w char to match.

- http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=425413